# Control side that shortens when changing div height on hover

Tags: html, css

I'm using this hover effect for buttons, but in a few cases when the height changes, the top remains the same and the bottom moves up, instead of vice versa like it should. How can I make sure it always goes in the correct direction?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zy7ue51k/1/)

```css
.button {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 215px;
  height: 55px;
  color: white;
  font-family: $arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(43, 36, 36, 0.35);
  letter-spacing: .1em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  position: relative;
  background: #009ee0;
  border: 1px solid #148fc6;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #148fc6;
}
.button:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px;
  height: 53px;
}
.button span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-43%);
  line-height: 1.2;
}
div {
  padding: 20px 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    <span>Wrong way</span>
  </a>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    <span>I work fine</span>
  </a>
  <a href="#" class="button">
    <span>I work fine</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you create an example where it does this in codepen/jsfiddle?

Answer (score 3):

You're reducing the height from 55px to 53px.  That 2px has to go somewhere.  The top button is just collapsing it.  (The bottom two are doing the same, it just doesn't look like it because they are being affected by vertical text alignment).  change your hover rule to this to accommodate for the height loss.

```
.button:hover {
  border-bottom: 1px;
  margin-top: 2px;
  height: 53px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/exd6hhvz/

Comment: i noticed another thing that if there are two buttons in div it doesn't really show a wrong behaviour. check here https://plnkr.co/edit/CghXYAtnCWU19gWhYUMR?p=preview. It has same HTML and CSS just an extra button is added

Comment: @S4beR That's because of vertical alignment.  One or the other button is keeping the height of the container because you can only hover on one at a time.  With that being the case, the buttons are trying to maintain the same baseline because of the default `vertical-align: baseline` that is applied to inline-block elements.  Add `vertical-align:top` to the buttons and you'll see the faulty behaviour again.

Comment: @S4beR See here: https://plnkr.co/edit/TVRzED4NaafA2cF1Fm5p?p=preview.  All I've done is add `vertical-align:top` to the `.button` CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make it work consistently by adding `margin-top: 2px;` to `.button:hover`

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/vf03czp5/